# Question about words in context of renting in order to owning

Tags: word-meaning, legalese

> **Monthly mortgage** has been **roughly** calculated using 25% **down**, 6% **interest** and 25 years **amortization**
>
> Source: http://www.ottawaliving.ca/property.php?property_id=38161

I was wondering if you could help me, simplifying the highlighted words above.

Comment: Your monthly mortgage payment is approximately calculated, assuming that the down payment is at 25%, with flat (fixed) interest rate at 6%, and with the period of 25 years.

Comment: *Down* means *down payment*; the meaning of this and the rest of these terms may be derived from a good dictionary. Consult one, and then feel free to bring specific questions back to us.

Comment: Please note that the website looks like it was designed to show properties *for sale*. The property you link to is a property *for rent*  The monthly rental fee is shown in the home price field on the website.  Therefore the information given about monthly mortgage payments etc, does not apply here and should just be ignored. Bottomline: you *can't* buy this place for $6/month, but you *can* live there for $1295/month.

Answer (score 1):

The web page with the original example probably confused the purchase price (probably about $268,000) with the monthly P&I payment (probably $1,295 per month). The web page therefore said that a $1,295 purchase price could be paid for with a down payment of $324 and a monthly payment of $6.26.

**monthly mortgage** is supposed to be your total payment you have to make each month to the bank for your home. Unfortunately, this example only includes the monthly principal and interest (P&I) payments -- it does not include property taxes, homeowners' insurance, condominium association dues, utilities, or other expenses.

**roughly** in this case just means *not exact*. An estimate.  Here are a few of the reasons your payments might vary:

- You might choose a different down payment.
- The example does not consider costs to get the loan, such as points and fees.
- The example does not consider costs when the loan finishes, such as deed recording fees.
- You might get a different interest rate.
- Different months have different numbers of days, so the monthly interest will vary.
- You might not always pay exactly on the due date.
- You might incur late fees.
- The bank will want you to pay your property taxes, homeowners' insurance, and condominium association fees every month as part of your mortgage payment.

**down** is just a shorthand way of saying *down payment*.  The down payment is the payment you make to the bank at the beginning of your loan/mortgage showing them that you are serious about paying this loan they gave you off. That you won't just borrow the money for the home and not pay them back.

**points** are a payment that you make to the bank at the beginning of the loan to get a better interest rate.  This fee is calculated as a percentage of the loan amount.  Zero, one, and two percentage points are common numbers of points.  This example assumes you do not pay any points or other fees at the start of the loan.

**interest** is how much the bank charges you for the loan. In this case they are charging 6% per year (or 1/2 percent per month).

So if the home you bought is $133,333, and you made a 25% down payment of 33,333, then your initial loan balance would be $100,000. In this example, the bank would make $500 in interest during the first full month; the amount of monthly interest would decline as you pay down the balance.

If in this example, your monthly **principal & interest (P&I)** payment was $644.30, you would owe 99,855.70 the second month. The bank would make $499.28 in interest during the second full month. After ten years of paying $644.30 per month, you would owe 76,352.21, and the bank would make $381.76 in interest during the 121st full month. After twenty-five years of paying $644.30 per month, you would have paid off the mortgage. (In addition to the $644.30 per month, you would also need to pay for property taxes, homeowners' insurance, condominium association fees, *et cetera*.)

The total amount of interest payments over the course of the loan is the total of the P&I payments minus the total of the principal payments. In this example:

> 300 months * $644.30 per month - $100,000 total principal payments
>
> = 93,290.42, more or less.

**principal** is the amount you owe at any given time.

**monthly principal payment** is the portion of your monthly payment that reduces the principal.

**amortization** is basically just the length of time that you have to pay the loan back. For a given interest rate, lengthening the amortization period will reduce your monthly payment. There are four disadvantages to a longer amortization period:

- You will not own your home outright until you have it all paid off.
- You will owe more money at any given time (before the loan is paid off), so you will pay more interest in any given month.
- You will owe money longer, so you will pay interest for more months.
- Banks usually charge higher interest rates on longer-term loans.

So if you went with a 15-year mortgage instead of 25-year mortgage, you would likely get a lower interest rate from the bank and own your home 10 years sooner, but your monthly payments would be a lot higher than with a 25-year mortgage. For more info about amortization read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortization)

Comment: The interest figure is annual, 6% each year, not 6% over the lifetime of the mortgage. And *amortization* here is shorthand for *amortization period*, the period of time during which the loan is progressively amortized.

Comment: As StoneyB says, the interest is compounded monthly.  This means that the portion of the monthly payment that goes toward interest is calculated by multiplying the remaining principle by the monthly interest rate (in this case 6% annual divided by 12 months per year, or 0.005%/month) On a $100,000 loan your first monthly payment would include $500 for interest on the loan. Anything above that (not counting escrow contributions) would be applied to reduce your principle and in turn, lower the principle for next month's interest calculation.